# Unable to debug UDPclient client receive

Tags: c#, console-application, udpclient

I want to receive packets from the IP address below using the following port. The problem is after **"client.Receive(ref localEp);"** this line the code does not run and also unable to debug.

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient();

IPEndPoint localEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 17000);
client.Client.Bind(localEp);

IPAddress multicastaddress = IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.10");
client.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);

while (true)
{
     Byte[] data = client.Receive(ref localEp);
     string strData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
     Console.WriteLine(strData);
}
```

I also get this exception ScopeId = 'localEp.Address.ScopeId' threw an exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in IPEndPoint localEp. Please help correcting my code

**UPDATE** The solution is, in my machine HYPER-V virtual machine setup is installed, which restricts this udp data from receiving. I just disabled it and started receiving data. To be honest, I have no idea with its behavior.

Comment: maybe the problem is with port 17000. try other ports.

Comment: I checked with some other values and the default value 0, same problem!! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try msdn way to  receive data from any source from localhost, and then from other host name:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// This constructor arbitrarily assigns the local port number.
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(17000);

    udpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 17000);

    // Sends a message to the host to which you have connected.
    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Is anybody there?");

    udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

    //// Sends a message to a different host using optional hostname and port parameters.
    //UdpClient udpClientB = new UdpClient();
    //udpClientB.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, "AlternateHostMachineName", 17000);

    //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
    Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
    string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
```

Comment: Works fine with the local host. I guess the problem is with the server, which is not sending any data. BTW, thanks for the answer

Comment: UDP has security risks. search google with 'security risks'. the firewall could block it.

Comment: Correct, I also added some inbound rules in the firewall for UDP connection to make it work